# Wicket TreeTable remove nodes icon

Tags: java, tree, treeview, wicket

Is there a way to remove the notes icon from the TreeTable component? I've searched in a lot of places but I can't find a way to remove it.

The docs says getNodeIcon and newNodeIcon are inherited from DefaultAbstractTree but I can't call them or override them. And I'm not very sure if they are the solution to my problem. Is there a way to

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try whether it works but I think you can override the method like this to achieve what you want:

```
new TreeTable("treetable", columns) {
    @Override
    protected Component newNodeIcon(MarkupContainer parent, String id, TreeNode node) {
        Component icon = new Label(id, "");
        icon.setVisible(false);
        return icon;
    }
};
```